# Duvida replace no pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Duvida no replace no dataframe pandas

```
texto = 'Vírus de computadores são uma lenda urbana.'

dado = {'texto': [texto]}
df = pd.DataFrame(dado)

df['nova_coluna'] = df.texto.str.replace('urbana', '')
```

Ao criar essa nova coluna podemos comprarar que a palavra 'urbana' foi retidada

porém se colocar essa expressão dentro do for não da certo

```
palavras = 'computadores', 'uma', 'lenda'

for palavra in palavras:

    df['nova_coluna'] = df.texto.str.replace(palavra, '')
```

é criado a coluna mas as palavras não são trocadas

Answer (score 2):

O problema é que quando você faz `df['nova_coluna'] = df.texto.str.replace(palavra, '')`
você esta alterando o texto original a todo o momento, ou seja, uma iteração você remove 'computadores' e não salva, depois 'uma' e não faz nada.

```
import pandas as pd

texto = 'Vírus de computadores são uma lenda urbana.'

dado = {'texto': [texto]}
df = pd.DataFrame(dado)

palavras = 'computadores', 'uma', 'lenda'

for item in range(len(palavras)):

    texto = texto.replace(palavras[item], '')

df['nova_coluna'] = texto
```

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro `palavras` terá conteúdo: "lenda". A declaração correta de listas é:

```
palavras = ['computadores', 'uma', 'lenda']
```

Depois vem o próximo problema. `df['texto']` tem apenas 1 valor (o termo correto é outro na verdade) e se substituir os valores da lista `palavras`, meu `df['texto']` teria 3 valores. O que é um problema. Então vou mostrar uma forma de resolver e depois você adapta para o que realmente precisa :)

```
import pandas as pd


texto = 'Vírus de computadores são uma lenda urbana.'

dado = {'texto': [texto]}
df = pd.DataFrame(dado)

df['nova_coluna'] = df.texto.str.replace('urbana', '')

for palavra in palavras:
   df['nova_coluna'] = df.texto.replace(palavra, '')
df
```

Nesse caso o valor de `df.nova_coluna` é apenas um. Porém, ela passou por 3 valores em cada iteração do laço:

- 1: 'Vírus de são uma lenda urbana.'
- 2: 'Vírus de computadores são lenda urbana.'
- 3: 'Vírus de computadores são uma urbana.'

Pois o valor de `df.texto` ('Vírus de computadores são uma lenda urbana') vai ser sempre usado para definir o valor de `df.nova_coluna`.